# ein Problem angehen vs. an ein Problem herangehen

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, meaning-in-context, idiomaticity

+Laut Wörterbuch könnte man sagen, dass ANGEHEN und HERANGEHEN als Synonyme verwendet werden können. Es scheint aber, dass ANGEHEN ein größeres semantisches Feld hat. In den folgenden Sätzen, zum Beispiel. Was wäre der Unterschied?

> 1.Es ist wichtig zu wissen, wie man ein Problem angeht.
>
> 2.Es ist wichtig zu wissen, wie man an ein Problem herangeht.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wie du richtig erkannt hast, überlappen sich die semantischen Felder der beiden Verben. Das heißt, sie überlappen sich weitgehend, sind aber nicht ganz gleich. Mit *»herangehen«* zielt man eher auf die Vorbereitung zur Problemlösung an, während *»angehen«* den konkreten Beginn der Problembehandlung beschreibt.

> Jürgens übliche Methode, an solche Probleme **heranzugehen**, bestand darin, vorher die Bedienungsanleitung zu lesen.
>
> Norbert **ging** das Problem **an**, indem er versuchte, mit einem Messgerät die schadhafte Stelle zu finden.

Aber wie gesagt: Die Bedeutungen sind fast dieselben, die Unterschiede sind daher minimal.

Comment: Zu Deiner Herangehensweise, die Frage zu beantworten, kann man nur sagen: So soll man es angehen!

Answer (score 4):

Ersetze in deinen Beispielsätzen "Problem" durch "eine Person".

> Es ist wichtig zu wissen, wie man eine Person angeht.

vs.

> Es ist wichtig zu wissen, wie man an eine Person herangeht.

"Angehen" stellt einen Angriff dar, "Herangehen" eine Annäherung. Einem Problem dürfte es relativ egal sein, ob man es angreift oder sich ihm nähert (und der Effekt - und damit die Bedeutung des Satzes - dürfte ungefähr auf dasselbe herauskommen, nämlich der Versuch, das Problem zu lösen). Bei einer Person dürfte es sehr wohl einen Unterschied machen, ob man sie angreift oder sich ihr annähert.

Comment: *Angreifen* kann man sich ja auch lediglich als *an etwas greifen* vorstellen.

Comment: @Janka  Ist das nicht ein Schwabizismus? - *Du sollsch dia Ziggerle it aagreifa!* - Deutsch: *Lass die Pfoten von den Bonbons!*

Comment: Eben. Mann kann seinen Boss um eine Gehaltserhöhung angehen. Und näher an den Affenkäfig herangehen. Beides nicht umgekehrt.